# How to include plugins with PhoneGap 3.5

Tags: cordova, plugins

I need to use plugins with PhoneGap, but none of them have been working as expected so far. It seems the documentation is lacking.

Let's take a simple example: let's say I want to use the FileUploadOptions class from the org.apache.cordova.file-transfer plugin.

I would first download the plugin:

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

The documentation for this plugin goes no further than this...
What am I supposed to do to get access to FileUploadOptions after that ?

Documentation for other plugins (such as barcodescanner.js) imply that I should add something such as this to my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
```

However, if I simply do this, the variable cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner don't exist. And neither does the deprecated variable window.plugins.barcodeScanner.

I don't understand how one is supposed to use these plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

In the following link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html you have a list of PhoneGap plugins. Clicking on one of the list items show docs for it. You can also use the Plugin Registry to also find 3rd party plugins http://plugins.cordova.io/#/ .

For example for the File Transfer plugin you can read more about it by following the link in the first url to this page https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md . Here you can read documentation about this particular plugin, how to install it, supported platforms, class properties and even example usage.

The usage for each PhoneGap plugin probably differs a little bit and therefor you should read about each one you want to use.

Comment: Clicking on respective list items related link are broken as of now. You can search for required plugin in http://plugreg.com/plugins and integrate accordingly.

Comment: You can also find suitable Phonegap plugins in https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

Answer (score 0):

For barcode scanner, you need to install it manually. I suggest u using scandit barcode scanner.

For ios

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/16/integration-scandit-phonegap-barcode-scanner-plugin-on-ipad-with-worklight-6-1/